# Is there a more efficient way to write SQL to group counts by date and column value

Tags: sql, h2

I have a status value of -1 or 1 stored in an `H2` database at regular intervals and I need a count of how many -1's and 1's have been stored by month for the last 12 months. The following code works but I am going to use it as a derived table in multiple places and would like to know if there is a more efficient way of doing it.

```
SELECT  STATUS_CODE AS STATUS,
    COUNT(*) AS STATUS_COUNT,
    CASE    
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-1,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 1'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-2,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 2'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-3,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 3'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-4,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 4'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-5,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 5'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-6,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 6'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-7,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 7'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-8,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 8'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-9,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 9'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-10,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 10'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-11,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 11'
        WHEN EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-12,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)   THEN 'MONTH 12'
        ELSE 'DONE' 
    END AS WEEK_RANGE
FROM    MY_TABLE 
WHERE   EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-12,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME) 
GROUP BY STATUS_CODE,  WEEK_RANGE
order by week_range
```

The results from running the previous code.

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `DATEDIFF()` to dynamically compute the difference between `log_entry_time` and the current date, in months:

```
SELECT  
    status_code AS status,
    COUNT(*) AS status_count,
    DATEDIFF(MONTH, log_entry_time, CURRENT_DATE) month_range
FROM MY_TABLE 
WHERE log_entry_time  >= DATEADD(MONTH, -12, CURRENT_DATE)
GROUP BY status_code, month_range
ORDER BY month_range
```

If `LOG_ENTRY_TIME` is of a `date`-like datatype, do not convert it to epoch for comparison, since doing so prevents the use of an index on that column. You can do date comparison instead, as show in the `WHERE` clause of the above query.

Comment: I think you need to fix your `order by week_range`.

Comment: @Marc: thanks, I fixed the typo. I did rename that column from `week_range` to `month_range`, because it better fits the purpose of the column.

Comment: I had similar code by week and forgot to change the name to month.  This worked for me and is much more concise than my original code..

Answer (score 1):

Would something like this be more useful?

```
SELECT  STATUS_CODE AS STATUS,
        COUNT(*) AS STATUS_COUNT,
        EXTRACT(YEAR FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME) || '-' || EXTRACT(MONTH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME)
FROM    MY_TABLE 
WHERE   EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM DATEADD(MONTH,-12,CURRENT_DATE)) < EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM LOG_ENTRY_TIME) 
GROUP BY STATUS_CODE,  WEEK_RANGE
order by week_range;
```

This is a little different from what your query does, but this one provides actual month values (e.g., "2019-12") for traceability rather than generic "Month N" labels.  Even if not exactly what you're trying to achieve, perhaps this will give an idea.

(I'm not sure what an H2 equivalent of Oracle's `TRUNC()` is, but that would help gather data for full months rather than to the current day of a prior month; that's sort of what I was trying to achieve.)

Comment: Thanks for the idea of pulling the date from the data.  I did something similar in my final code.